# Refresh picker selection when published variable is reset

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a published variable that keeps track in this case, an amount of time. When a user saves their values, the variable will be reset (in this case back to an empty string. My recipeClass is updated correctly (as I can see my variable updating to the users selection, then back to "" when submitted. I'll include the published variable below here for reference:

```
 @Published var recipePrepTime:   String = ""
```

My Picker in the view is just not updating back to the initial value, in this case "5 minutes" How can I accomplish this? Any feedback would be great. Please find my code below:

```
struct RecipeEditorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var recipeClass: Recipe
    //@State var recipeTitle = ""
    @State private var recipeTime = "Cook Time"
    @State private var pickerTime: String = ""
    //calls macro pickers
    var cookingTime = ["5 Mins", "10 Mins","15 Mins","20 Mins","25 Mins","30 Mins ","45 Mins ","1 Hour","2 Hours", "A Long Time", "A Very Long Time"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
            HStack(spacing: 0){
                ZStack{
                    Image(systemName:("clock"))
                        .padding(.leading, 150)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("completeGreen"))
//picker I would like updated
                    Picker(selection: $recipeClass.recipePrepTime, label: Text("")) {
                       ForEach(cookingTime, id: \.self) {
                           Text($0)
                       }
                    }
                    
                    .onChange(of: pickerTime, perform: { _ in
                        recipeClass.recipePrepTime = pickerTime
                      
                    })
                    .accentColor(.gray)
                }
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
        }
       
    }
       
}
```

Noting I didn't include my recipeClass as the values are being correctly updated on the backend.

Comment: Set recipePrepTime to value that you have in the array instead of "", like "5 Mins".

Comment: And I don't understand the use of `changeOf`, recipeClass.recipePrepTime is already chosen as the Picker selection parameter so why update it again?

Comment: As mentioned, where the user save their selection, use something like this:
   `Button("save") { recipeClass.recipePrepTime = cookingTime[0] }`. Note, remove the `.onChange` it is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks all - switching to "5mins" vs "" did the trick